# Reading a file in java by a delimeter

Tags: java

I have an image file with another file appended to the end of it, separated by a string delimiter. What I'm trying to do is separate the 2 files in java to write the file appended to the end into it's own file, I've tried a few solutions however they either corrupted the file or were hopelessly inefficient. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Here's the best solution I have so far, it almost works but corrupts the file slightly.

```
public class FileExtractor {

    private static final String START_OF_FILE_DATA = "SOFD34qjknhwe3rjkhw";

    public void extractFile(String[] files)
    {
        try 
        {
            String first = readFileToString(files[0]);
            Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(START_OF_FILE_DATA + "(.*)" + START_OF_FILE_DATA + "(.*)", Pattern.DOTALL);
            Matcher matcher1 = p1.matcher(first);
            String filename = "";
            if(matcher1.find())
            {
                filename = matcher1.group(1);
            }
            else
            {
                //throw exception of corrupted file
            }
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("buildtest/" + filename));
            out.write(matcher1.group(2).getBytes("cp1251"), 0, matcher1.group(2).length());
            for (int i = 1; i < files.length; i++) 
            {
                String content = readFileToString(files[i]);
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile(START_OF_FILE_DATA + "(.*)", Pattern.DOTALL);
                Matcher matcher = p.matcher(content);
                if(matcher.find())
                {
                    out.write(matcher.group(1).getBytes("cp1251"), 0, matcher.group(1).length());
                }
                else
                {
                    //throw exception of corrupted file
                }
            }
            out.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private String readFileToString(String file)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) new File(file).length()];
        BufferedInputStream f = null;
        try {
            f = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            f.read(buffer);
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        finally 
        {
            if (f != null) {
                try {
                    f.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                }
            }
        }
        String ret = "";
        try
        {
            ret = new String(buffer, "cp1251");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        return ret;

    }
```

Comment: Can you post some code showing how you're trying to do it?

Comment: Do you expect it to be a valid image file when the string is appended to it?

Comment: I've appended the code now that I have so far.

Comment: I have to second what @JamesBlack was saying: how can a data file such as an image file (such as a jpg, bmp, or png file) be mixed with a text file or line of text and hope to make any sense?

Comment: Very easily actually: http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/hide-file-in-picture/
It works for gifs as well before you ask

Comment: Are you the one who merge the two files together? If so, use [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) to write a header that contains the size of the image and the size of the text file. Then, append the two files. When you want to read the text file, use [`skipBytes(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#skipBytes(int)) of [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) to skip the header and the image and then read the text file.

Comment: ^good idea, just tried that and it worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Yawn: remember to mark as accepted the answer you are happy with.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to operate file as a byte array, not a string. So you need to find where the sequence of bytes start.

```
byte[] fileData = // read the file into a byte array
byte[] separator = separatorString.getBytes();
int index = 0;
for (;;) {
    int start = index;
    index = findIndexOf(fileData, separator, start);
    if (index == -1) break;
    byte[] nextImage = new byte[index - start + 1];
    System.arrayCopy(fileData, start, nextImage, 0, nextImage.length);
    saveAsImage(nextImage);
    index += separator.length;
}
```

Of course you need to implement `findIndexOf(byte[] where,  byte[] what, int startIndex)` (just take a look into `String.indexOf` implementation). I hope it helps.

Comment: because it's an image file, not a string. and it gets corrupted when you treat as a string.

Comment: are you sure? I remember handling images like this, but that might have been PHP. Since you can read the entire image at one time, I'm pretty sure it wouldn't corrupt.

Comment: I think `Scanner` is going to work, since it will recognize the `delimiter` and start reading the text file after that. BUT, there is no guarantee that it won't read the `delimiter` from the image binary (in case of finding a binary chunk that is equivalent to the `delimiter`).

Comment: Guys, this is an image. You cannot convert it to a string, and then back to a byte array without changing its contents. At least you cannot guarantee it won't happen.

Answer (score 1):

[`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) does this with the `useDelimiter()` method. Basically:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(your_file_name));
in.useDelimiter(START_OF_FILE_DATA);

String first = in.next();   // Read the first part
String seconds = in.next(); // Read the second part

// Save the separate files
```

Comment: Is there a way of reading it into a byte array instead, putting it into a string tends to corrupt the data

Comment: Well, it could work well in some cases. But, in other cases, it could read the `delimiter` from the image part (since it 's binary, and it might contain the binary that is equivalent to the `delimiter` binary representation).

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.io.Files;

    public class FileExtractor {

    private static final int START_OF_FILE_DATA = 0x1C;
    private static final String TEST_FILE_NAME = "test.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {//test
        String separator = String.valueOf((char) START_OF_FILE_DATA);
        String bigFile = "file one" + separator + "second file" + separator + "file No. 3";
        Files.write(bigFile.getBytes(), new File(TEST_FILE_NAME));//create big file in project directory

        new FileExtractor().extractFile(TEST_FILE_NAME);
    }

    public void extractFile(String bigFile) {
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(bigFile);) {

            List<byte[]> files = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int in;
            while ((in = fis.read()) != -1) {//read 1 byte from file until the file ends
                if (in == START_OF_FILE_DATA) {//START_OF_FILE_DATA have length 1 byte. For longer you need to remake it.
                    files.add(baos.toByteArray());
                    baos.reset();
                }
                baos.write(in);//beware, START_OF_FILE_DATA will be included in the file
            }

            files.add(baos.toByteArray());

            for (byte[] file : files)
                System.out.println("next file:\n" + new String(file));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**
next file:
file one
next file:
second file
next file:
file No. 3